# H2 and Oracle Compatiability issues

Tags: oracle, maven-3, h2, flyway

I am having an issue executing the following script using Flyway and H2 database.  I assume its a Oracle compatibility issue but I am using H2 with the correct mode.  This script is used to construct my tables in production but I want to use an in-memory database for testing purposes.  Setup and error below.  I don't want rewrite the scripts for an in-memory database if thats possible.

Jdbc.properties

```
jdbc.driver=org.h2.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:file:target/firmsoftDB;MODE=Oracle
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=
```

Sql Script

```
CREATE TABLE USER_INFO
(
  USER_INFO_ID      NUMBER                      NOT NULL,
  USER_NAME         VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)           NOT NULL,
  EMAIL             VARCHAR2(320 BYTE)              NULL,
  LAST_NAME         VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)           NOT NULL,
  FIRST_NAME        VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)           NOT NULL,
  LAST_LOGIN        TIMESTAMP(6)                    NULL,
  USER_TYPE         VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)               NULL,
  USER_CN           VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)               NULL,
  SOURCE_DIRECTORY  VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)               NULL,
  PRIMARY_PHONE     VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)               NULL,
  ALT_PHONE         VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)               NULL,
  CREATED_BY        NUMBER                      NOT NULL,
  CREATED_DATE      TIMESTAMP(6)                NOT NULL,
  UPDATED_BY        NUMBER                      NOT NULL,
  UPDATED_DATE      TIMESTAMP(6)                NOT NULL
)
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING;
```

pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>h2-test</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <flyway.locations>db/migration</flyway.locations>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                        <threadCount>1</threadCount>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <executions>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- <url>jdbc:hsqldb:file:target/firmsoftDB;sql.syntax_ora=true</url> -->
                        <!-- <url>jdbc:hsqldb:mem:firmsoftDB;sql.syntax_ora=true</url> -->
                        <url>jdbc:h2:file:target/firmsoftDB;MODE=Oracle</url>
                        <!-- <url>jdbc:derby:\temp\db\FAQ\db</url> -->
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd">

   <!--  Needed for system properties replacement -->
    <!-- Following will only work with spring 3     -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:jdbc.properties,classpath*:flyway.default.properties,classpath*:flyway.properties"
            ignore-resource-not-found="true"        
    system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>

    <!-- flyway part -->
    <bean id="flyway" class="com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway" depends-on="dataSourceRef">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceRef"/>
        <property name="locations" value="${flyway.locations}"/>
    </bean>

 <bean id="dataSourceRef" name="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">

            <property name="driverClassName"><value>${jdbc.driver}</value></property>
            <property name="url"><value>${jdbc.url}</value></property>
            <property name="username"><value>${jdbc.username}</value></property>
            <property name="password"><value>${jdbc.password}</value></property>
            <property name="maxActive" value="-1"/>

</bean>
```

StackTrace

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.googlecode.flyway:flyway-maven-plugin:2.2.1:migrate (default-cli) on project flyway-test: com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Migration of schema "PUBLIC" to version 1 failed! Please restore backups and roll back database and code! Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE USER_INFO
[ERROR] (
[ERROR] USER_INFO_ID      NUMBER                      NOT NULL,
[ERROR] USER_NAME         VARCHAR2(32 BYTE[*])           NOT NULL,
[ERROR] EMAIL             VARCHAR2(320 BYTE)              NULL,
[ERROR] LAST_NAME         VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)           NOT NULL,
[ERROR] FIRST_NAME        VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)           NOT NULL,
[ERROR] LAST_LOGIN        TIMESTAMP(6)                    NULL,
[ERROR] USER_TYPE         VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)               NULL,
[ERROR] USER_CN           VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)               NULL,
[ERROR] SOURCE_DIRECTORY  VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)               NULL,
[ERROR] PRIMARY_PHONE     VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)               NULL,
[ERROR] ALT_PHONE         VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)               NULL,
[ERROR] CREATED_BY        NUMBER                      NOT NULL,
[ERROR] CREATED_DATE      TIMESTAMP(6)                NOT NULL,
[ERROR] UPDATED_BY        NUMBER                      NOT NULL,
[ERROR] UPDATED_DATE      TIMESTAMP(6)                NOT NULL
[ERROR] )
[ERROR] LOGGING
[ERROR] NOCOMPRESS
[ERROR] NOCACHE
[ERROR] NOPARALLEL
[ERROR] MONITORING"; expected "K, M, G, CHAR, )"; SQL statement:
[ERROR] CREATE TABLE USER_INFO
[ERROR] (
[ERROR] USER_INFO_ID      NUMBER                      NOT NULL,
[ERROR] USER_NAME         VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)           NOT NULL,
[ERROR] EMAIL             VARCHAR2(320 BYTE)              NULL,
[ERROR] LAST_NAME         VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)           NOT NULL,
[ERROR] FIRST_NAME        VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)           NOT NULL,
[ERROR] LAST_LOGIN        TIMESTAMP(6)                    NULL,
[ERROR] USER_TYPE         VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)               NULL,
[ERROR] USER_CN           VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)               NULL,
[ERROR] SOURCE_DIRECTORY  VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)               NULL,
[ERROR] PRIMARY_PHONE     VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)               NULL,
[ERROR] ALT_PHONE         VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)               NULL,
[ERROR] CREATED_BY        NUMBER                      NOT NULL,
[ERROR] CREATED_DATE      TIMESTAMP(6)                NOT NULL,
[ERROR] UPDATED_BY        NUMBER                      NOT NULL,
[ERROR] UPDATED_DATE      TIMESTAMP(6)                NOT NULL
[ERROR] )
[ERROR] LOGGING
[ERROR] NOCOMPRESS
[ERROR] NOCACHE
[ERROR] NOPARALLEL
[ERROR] MONITORING [42001-174]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.googlecode.flyway:flyway-maven-plugin:2.2.1:migrate (default-cli) on project flyway-test: com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Migration of schema "PUBLIC" to version 1 failed! Please restore backups and roll back database and code!
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Migration of schema "PUBLIC" to version 1 failed! Please restore backups and roll back database and code!
    at com.googlecode.flyway.maven.AbstractFlywayMojo.execute(AbstractFlywayMojo.java:253)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE USER_INFO
(
  USER_INFO_ID      NUMBER                      NOT NULL,
  USER_NAME         VARCHAR2(32 BYTE[*])           NOT NULL,
  EMAIL             VARCHAR2(320 BYTE)              NULL,
  LAST_NAME         VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)           NOT NULL,
  FIRST_NAME        VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)           NOT NULL,
  LAST_LOGIN        TIMESTAMP(6)                    NULL,
  USER_TYPE         VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)               NULL,
  USER_CN           VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)               NULL,
  SOURCE_DIRECTORY  VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)               NULL,
  PRIMARY_PHONE     VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)               NULL,
  ALT_PHONE         VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)               NULL,
  CREATED_BY        NUMBER                      NOT NULL,
  CREATED_DATE      TIMESTAMP(6)                NOT NULL,
  UPDATED_BY        NUMBER                      NOT NULL,
  UPDATED_DATE      TIMESTAMP(6)                NOT NULL
)
LOGGING
NOCOMPRESS
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING"; expected "K, M, G, CHAR, )"; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE USER_INFO
(
  USER_INFO_ID      NUMBER                      NOT NULL,
  USER_NAME         VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)           NOT NULL,
  EMAIL             VARCHAR2(320 BYTE)              NULL,
  LAST_NAME         VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)           NOT NULL,
  FIRST_NAME        VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)           NOT NULL,
  LAST_LOGIN        TIMESTAMP(6)                    NULL,
  USER_TYPE         VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)               NULL,
  USER_CN           VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)               NULL,
  SOURCE_DIRECTORY  VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)               NULL,
  PRIMARY_PHONE     VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)               NULL,
  ALT_PHONE         VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)               NULL,
  CREATED_BY        NUMBER                      NOT NULL,
  CREATED_DATE      TIMESTAMP(6)                NOT NULL,
  UPDATED_BY        NUMBER                      NOT NULL,
  UPDATED_DATE      TIMESTAMP(6)                NOT NULL
)
LOGGING
NOCOMPRESS
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING [42001-174]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:332)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:197)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:504)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.read(Parser.java:2867)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnWithType(Parser.java:3788)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnForTable(Parser.java:3603)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreateTable(Parser.java:5354)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreate(Parser.java:3890)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:334)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:289)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:265)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:226)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:437)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:380)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1138)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:168)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:156)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate.executeStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:230)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.SqlScript.execute(SqlScript.java:89)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationExecutor.execute(SqlMigrationExecutor.java:72)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate$2.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:252)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate$2.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:250)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:56)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate.applyMigration(DbMigrate.java:250)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate.access$700(DbMigrate.java:47)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate$1.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:189)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate$1.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:138)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:56)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate.migrate(DbMigrate.java:137)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:872)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:819)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1200)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:819)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.maven.MigrateMojo.doExecuteWithMigrationConfig(MigrateMojo.java:159)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.maven.AbstractMigrationLoadingMojo.doExecute(AbstractMigrationLoadingMojo.java:151)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.maven.AbstractFlywayMojo.execute(AbstractFlywayMojo.java:251)
    ... 21 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Do you really need that the varchar2 be as Bytes? You can specify just the size like this: `USER_NAME VARCHAR2(32)` try it. And for the other columns too.

Comment: This schema in its current form is the schema that is currently in use, im not looking to change this schema.  I want the schema I use in testing to reflect the one in production.

Comment: Can you put all stacktrace? Also, MONITORING is deprecated according oracle docs.

Comment: added stacktrace, I think i've just hit a limitation here with H2 and HSQLDB, It does work if I substitute VARCHAR2 for VARCHAR and remove the following keywords LOGGING
NOCOMPRESS
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Short Answer

Oracle is a huge piece of software, and you can't expect a small embedded database to be 100% compatible.

### Long Answer

**Compatibility Modes**

As documented, [for certain features, this database can emulate the behavior of specific databases](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility). However, *only a small subset* of the differences between databases are implemented in this way. This list is documented.

**Compatibility**

As documented, [H2 is (*up to a certain point*) compatible to other databases](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#compatibility) such as HSQLDB, MySQL and PostgreSQL. There are certain areas where H2 is incompatible.

All database engines behave a little bit different. Where possible, H2 supports the ANSI SQL standard, and tries to be compatible to other databases. There are still differences however.

Answer (score 18):

H2 doesn't recognize the syntax

```
VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)
```

Change this to

```
VARCHAR2(32)
```

... and it will still work in oracle and will at least remove your first error in H2.

Comment: Small catch: If you don't explicitly specify BYTE or CHAR, Oracles interpretation will depend on the setting of *NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS* which is BYTE by default for backward compatibility, but might as well be set to CHAR by your DBA since the latter setting makes more sense when you're dealing with Strings.