# Flyway migration succeeds in MS SQL Server but fails in H2 database

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, h2, flyway

A database scheme in my application is managed by [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) migrations. These migrations are designed for MS SQL Server and have been executed a lot of times with no problems.

I've decided to reuse the migrations for setting up a testing database ([H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)) before running tests. And created the following beans in Spring context for this:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    // Scheme = test_db, Compatibility mode = MSSQLServer
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:test_db;MODE=MSSQLServer;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;" +
            "INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS test_db\\;SET SCHEMA test_db");
    dataSource.setUsername("sa");
    dataSource.setPassword("");

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public Flyway flyway() {
    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
    flyway.setDataSource(dataSource());
    flyway.setSchemas("test_db");
    flyway.setLocations("filesystem:db\\migration");
    flyway.migrate();  // Exception is thrown from here !!!
    return flyway;
}
```

But during Spring context initialization I get the following exception saying about a syntax error on the very first line of my migration script:

```
org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.FlywaySqlScriptException: Migration V1__init.sql failed

SQL State  : 42001
Error Code : 42001
Message    : Syntax error in SQL statement "SET XACT_ABORT[*] ON
...
```

Obviously there's some **compatibility issue between Flyway / MS SQL Server scripts / H2**, cause if I remove the line `SET XACT_ABORT[*] ON` from the migration script, it gives me another error.

I'm new in using in-memory database and I want to keep Flyway migrations unmodified. What are the other possible solutions?

Comment: I'm afraid that a huge MS SQL Server and a small embedded database can't be 100% compatible. Where possible, H2 supports the ANSI SQL standard, and tries to be compatible to other databases. There are still differences however. [(source)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20225815/1429387)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a database generated error, no a Flyway error. The two DBMS you are using are not fully compatible: some datatypes, functions, etc. accepted by MS SQL Server are not available in H2, SQL syntax is not identical and so on. That statement generating your error is specific to MS SQL Server (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql))

I don't know of any way that Flyway would automatically translate the DML scripts you use. You'll have to create your in memory schema yourself. Unless someone knows of any tools that do this automagically.

Tell us about your persistance layer, what framework are you using?

If you are testing a JPA Hibernate application then you could enable autogeneration of the schema at runtime (by setting [hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html) property in the persistence.xml used by your test app context). Of course you would still need to populate your schema with data. Possibly your scripts will work for this. A manual sollution for this could be, before any tests start, opening a second DB connection to your main database, selecting the data you need in your domain objects and then persisting them through your in memory DB connection. I didn't try this, just an idea...

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to generate H2 schema with Hibernate (though there will be some differences with actual schema used in MS SQL Server) and then populate it with DbUnit.