# normalizing or bucketing SQL timestamps in a standard way in Oracle/H2

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, h2

I have a `foo` SQL table in Oracle that has a `bar` timestamp. I want to update the timestamps so that they match the maximum timestamp in a 8–16 second range. (The timestamps come in "bunches" anyway; they are either under 8 seconds apart, or more than 16 seconds apart.) Oh, and I'm running tests with H2. I tried this:

```
UPDATE foo update_foo SET bar =
  (SELECT MAX(bar) FROM foo
    WHERE bar > update_foo.bar - interval '8' second
        AND bar < update_foo.bar + interval '8' second)
```

H2 didn't like that. Is my syntax correct for Oracle, if I want to do it in a standard way? Is the problem with H2, or with my syntax? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I love H2 but it's necessarily different from Oracle. This is one case where this tiny little database engine uses an alternative syntax for the same purpose. But I warn you it's not a copycat from Oracle.

Assuming your data is:

```
create table foo (
  bar timestamp
);

insert into foo (bar) values ('2018-01-01 12:34:56');
insert into foo (bar) values ('2018-01-01 12:34:52');
insert into foo (bar) values ('2018-01-01 12:34:57');
insert into foo (bar) values ('2018-01-02 12:34:10');
insert into foo (bar) values ('2018-01-02 12:34:11');
```

The query is:

```
update foo update_foo set bar =
  (select max(bar) from foo
    where bar > dateadd('second', -8, update_foo.bar)
        and bar < dateadd('second', 8, update_foo.bar)
);
```

Result:

```
BAR                      
---------------------
2018-01-01 12:34:57.0    
2018-01-01 12:34:57.0    
2018-01-01 12:34:57.0    
2018-01-02 12:34:11.0    
2018-01-02 12:34:11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It's H2. Your statement conforms to Oracle 12c and as far back as when timestamps were introduced (10g?).

The better way depends upon H2, which I don't know.

EDIT: You might look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220054/h2-and-oracle-compatiability-issues) for more details.

A brute force approach, which should be pretty slow, would be to open a cursor for

```
select key, max(bar) from foo group by key
```

and in a loop, fetch a row and execute this:

```
update foo set bar = max_fetched_bar where key = fetched_key
```

Horrible. Absolutely horrible. But maybe the update and select are simple enough to parse in H2.

If H2 supports executing anonymous PL/SQL blocks, then you could execute your original update in a PL/SQL block and hopefully avoid H2.